# DBO role in SQL Server 2005 versus DBA role?

Tags: sql-server, security, sql-server-2005

What is the difference between DBO role versus the DBA role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dba is not a system role, it's the title of the person who administers your database server (**D**ata **B**ase **A**dministrator).  There is no builtin role called "dba" in SQL.

High-level: DBO is the owner of the specific database and as such has the permissions to do anything within that datbase.

Comment: Thank you so much!  A quick follow on Q: so does that mean DBAs typically give themsevles DBO rights or Sys Admin rights?  Which takes precedence over the other I guess...

Comment: DBA's are typically the system administrators so it would follow that they are the ones that have sysadmin rights.  The sysadmin trumps all, gives full permission server-wide.  DBO only gives full permission at the database level.  Thus it won't give you the permission to do things like create and drop databases, set up server logins, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As squillman says, DBA isn't the name of a role. When you say DBA, I think you're meaning what's commonly called 'sa', or the 'sysadmin' server-level role.

DBOs (actually the 'db_owner' role) owns a database and has all permissions in the context of that database. For a list and description of all the database-level roles, see the Books Online topic [Database-Level Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189121.aspx).

Members of the sysadmin server-level role can do anything at all on the server, with no restrictions in scope or context. For a list and description of all the server-level roles, see the Books Online topic [Server-Level Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A DBA owns the whole sql server instance. A dbo is just the owner for his little database (but could be owner of more than one or all also)